prysmctl testnet generate-genesis could not generate genesis state
I am following steps in the documentation and according to the documentation, to move the values of shanghaiTime and timestamp in the genesis.json file I must run the command:
./prysmctl testnet generate-genesis --fork capella --num-validators 64 --genesis-time-delay 600 --chain-config-file config.yml --geth-genesis-json-in genesis.json  --geth-genesis-json-out genesis.json --output-ssz genesis.ssz

However I got the following error:
FATA[0000] Could not generate beacon chain genesis state  error="could not set config params: version 0x05000000 for fork electra in config interop conflicts with existing config named=mainnet: configset cannot add config with conflicting fork version schedule" prefix=genesis

